# Pick up block using pygame.KEYDOWN

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, block, keydown

I am trying to use `pygame.KEYDOWN` so that when I press the key represented by `pygame.K_q` the **block** that the **player** has collided with can be **dragged** (pick up) to where the player moves as it is done using `pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` in this [tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=pick_up_blocks.py).

But pressing the `q` key to drag the block does not work...

This need of mine arose when trying to implement this functionality in another larger code. So I decided to get this other [tutorial2](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/show_file.php?file=move_sprite_keyboard_jump.py) to set up my MWE. I looked to see if anyone had already asked about it but I just found relative but not exact questions that used a very different or very large code structure and I still haven't figured out why I can't get my MWE code to work. This should be a simple question and someone may have already posted this question, so if so let me know where there is a question already posted that clarifies my question.

My MWE:

```
import pygame
import random

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the block to be picked up.
    It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    """

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
        and its x and y position. """

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ The class is the player-controlled sprite. """

    carry_block_list = []

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Constructor function"""
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self):

        diff_x = self.rect.x - 4
        diff_y = self.rect.y - 4

        # Loop through each block that we are carrying and adjust
        # it by the amount we moved.
        for block in self.carry_block_list:
            block.rect.x -= diff_x
            block.rect.y -= diff_y
            print("something")

# Call this function so the Pygame library can initialize itself
pygame.init()

# Create an 800x600 sized screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

# Set the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Move Sprite With Keyboard')

# Create the player paddle object
player = Player(50, 50)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


for i in range(50):
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
               print("pick up")
            # When the mouse button is pressed, see if we are in contact with
            # other sprites:

               blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, False)

            # Set the list of blocks we are in contact with as the list of
            # blocks being carried.

               player.carry_block_list = blocks_hit_list

            if event.key == pygame.K_l:
               print("let go")
            # When we let up on the mouse, set the list of blocks we are
            # carrying as empty.

               player.carry_block_list = []

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.rect.x -= player.rect.width
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.rect.x += player.rect.width
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.rect.y -= player.rect.height
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.rect.y += player.rect.height

    # -- Draw everything
    # Clear screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # Draw sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # Flip screen
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Pause
    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: in code you use `p`, not `q` to drag it.

Comment: @furas grateful for the note I will be correcting the statement of the question...

Comment: first I would use `print()` to see values in variables and which code is executed. This way you can see if it executes code which should add block to list, move it and draw it.

Comment: you move blocks in `Player.update()` so I used `print()` in this function and it seems it is never executed.

Comment: @furas thankXD. I'm looking at your answer understanding what I did wrong...

Comment: I think you don't need new class or function. Eventually you can add `Block.update()` or `Block.move()` and run `block.update(diff_x, diff_y)` or `block.move(diff_x, diff_y)` inside `player.update()` - especially if `block.update()`/`block.move()` would do something more.

Comment: @furas I understand, I see how you organized the code. Thanks for clarifying about using another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You move blocks in `Player.update()` but you never execute it

First I tried to execute this function in every loop but finally I changed this function to run only when players is moved

```
def update(self, diff_x, diff_y):
    # Loop through each block that we are carrying and adjust
    # it by the amount we moved.
    for block in self.carry_block_list:
        block.rect.x += diff_x
        block.rect.y += diff_y
```

and

```
       if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player.rect.x -= player.rect.width
            player.update(-player.rect.width, 0)

        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player.rect.x += player.rect.width
            player.update(player.rect.width, 0)

        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player.rect.y -= player.rect.height
            player.update(0, -player.rect.height)

        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            player.rect.y += player.rect.height
            player.update(0, player.rect.height)
```

---

Full code:

```
import pygame
import random

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """
    This class represents the block to be picked up.
    It derives from the "Sprite" class in Pygame.
    """

    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        """ Constructor. Pass in the color of the block,
        and its x and y position. """

        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
        # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # image.
        # Update the position of this object by setting the values
        # of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ The class is the player-controlled sprite. """

    carry_block_list = []

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """Constructor function"""
        # Call the parent's constructor
        super().__init__()

        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        # Make our top-left corner the passed-in location.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def update(self, diff_x, diff_y):
        # Loop through each block that we are carrying and adjust
        # it by the amount we moved.
        for block in self.carry_block_list:
            block.rect.x += diff_x
            block.rect.y += diff_y


# Call this function so the Pygame library can initialize itself
pygame.init()

# Create an 800x600 sized screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

# Set the title of the window
pygame.display.set_caption('Move Sprite With Keyboard')

# Create the player paddle object
player = Player(50, 50)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


for i in range(50):
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(BLACK, 20, 15)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(screen_height)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:

            # When the mouse button is pressed, see if we are in contact with
            # other sprites:

               blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, block_list, False)

            # Set the list of blocks we are in contact with as the list of
            # blocks being carried.

               player.carry_block_list = blocks_hit_list

            if event.key == pygame.K_l:

            # When we let up on the mouse, set the list of blocks we are
            # carrying as empty.

               player.carry_block_list = []

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.rect.x -= player.rect.width
                player.update(-player.rect.width, 0)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.rect.x += player.rect.width
                player.update(player.rect.width, 0)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.rect.y -= player.rect.height
                player.update(0, -player.rect.height)

            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.rect.y += player.rect.height
                player.update(0, player.rect.height)



    # -- Draw everything
    # Clear screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # Draw sprites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # Flip screen
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Pause
    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```